# @font-face not working in CSS

Tags: css, font-face

I am using this line in my CSS code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('myserver/Fonts/tiza-webfont.ttf');
}
```

and then this one for a specific title:

```css
#h1{
  font-family: 'myFont';
}
```

I tried many font links and even tried to put some custom ones like "Comic Sans" but the font does not change.

**My HTML is:**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bbb.css">
</head>

<div id="table">
            <ul>
                <li><img id="icons" src="icon.jpg" alt="" /><h1> OPA: <strong> {Query.OPA} </strong></h1></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

I checked the Console and everything seems ok now. I tried checking the website on different browsers too.

Comment: Can you show your HTML too?

Comment: Is this folder `myserver/Fonts/tiza-webfont.ttf` inside `css` folder?

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Your HTML looks alright! Can you show a screenshot of what your Console says? Press `F12` and use Print Screen and get the screenshot of the Console.

Comment: what is the css folder name ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include all the glyphs from [here](https://github.com/avranju/instafuzz/tree/master/css/fonts/tiza). Including only `ttf` doesn't work in all browsers. Change your stylesheet to reflect something like this, which is the standard way:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFont';
    src: url('tiza-webfont.eot');
    src: url('tiza-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('tiza-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('tiza-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('tiza-webfont.svg#TizaRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And make sure you are adding this CSS file on the same directory as all your font files exist. And use the CSS to link here.

So if you have the font files (`ttf`, `svg`, `woff`, etc.) in the directory: `myserver/Fonts/`, then you need to add the CSS file like `tiza.css` in `myserver/Fonts/tiza.css`.

Make sure the above CSS is accessible publicly by a web browser through HTTP like:

```
http://mydomain/myserver/Fonts/tiza.css
```

And include it in your HTML like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain/myserver/Fonts/tiza.css" />
```

The main thing is that you must make sure you are clear of any `404` or `4xx` errors on your console. Something like this is what that makes it not work:

[image]

Comment: I put the fonts in a folder called "fonts" which is a subfolder of "css". But nothing changed.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Did you check the console?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Also check this link: https://cdn.rawgit.com/avranju/instafuzz/master/css/fonts/tiza/demo.html Tell me if you are able to see the font you wanna get?

Comment: I checked it and I get "Font from origin 'http://............co.uk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Aha!! That's the problem. You have to provide the CSS and files in the same server as this. `:)`

Comment: @ApoloRadomer Try including the CSS from the this url: https://cdn.rawgit.com/avranju/instafuzz/master/css/fonts/tiza/stylesheet.css And tell me if it works. Update your `font-family` to `TizaRegular`.

Comment: The reason it was not working is because of the permissions. The server has automatically changed all the permissions for font files. I had to change that. Now it works :)